# Unavailable exception for CassendraLog4net appenadar

Tags: log4j, cassandra

I want to develop a logging techniques using `CassandraLog4net Appender`. I am getting `Unavailable exception`.

Can u tell me whether i have to create a keyspace or database before running this code?

Also, I am not able to use `NODE TOOL` When i click on it, it disappears again.

what changes should I make?

Please, find details of configuration of `CassendraLog4netAppendar`.

```
 <KeyspaceName value="Logging" /><ColumnFamily value="LogEntries"/>\
 <PlacementStrategy value="org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy" />
 <StrategyOptions value="Datacentre1:1" /><ReplicationFactor value="1" />
 <ConsistencyLevel value="QUORUM" />
 <MaxBufferedRows value="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

UnavailableException means there aren't enough replicas available to satisfy your query.  From your configuration I see a lot of inconsistency in your cluster config.  Your log4net appender strategy options point to "Datacentre1"; your topology file lists a bunch of machines in "DC1", "DC2", and "DC3" with multiple racks; your keyspace is set up with only one DC called "DC1"; nodetool shows a single node listening on 127.0.0.1 (which doesn't correlate to any of your configured machines).  So you're getting UnavailableException because you're asking for something that doesn't exist.  You need to have a consistent configuration across the various pieces.

Comment: 192.168.1.100=DC1:RAC1 192.168.2.200=DC2:RAC2 10.0.0.10=DC1:RAC1 10.0.0.11=DC1:RAC1 10.0.0.12=DC1:RAC2 10.20.114.10=DC2:RAC1 10.20.114.11=DC2:RAC1 10.21.119.13=DC3:RAC1 10.21.119.10=DC3:RAC1 10.0.0.13=DC1:RAC2 10.21.119.14=DC3:RAC2 10.20.114.15=DC2:RAC2

Comment: Keyspace: Logging: Replication Strategy: org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy Durable Writes: true Options: [DC1:1] Column Families: ColumnFamily: LogEntries Key Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType Default column value validator: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type Columns sorted by: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type GC grace seconds: 864000 Compaction min/max thresholds: 4/32 Read repair chance: 0.1

Comment: DC Local Read repair chance: 0.0 Replicate on write: true Caching: KEYS_ONLY Bloom Filter FP chance: default Built indexes: [] Column Metadata: Column Name: log_timestamp Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType Compaction Strategy: org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompacti onStrategy Compression Options: sstable_compression: org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.SnappyCompressor [default@Logging]

Comment: Please have a look at my configuration posted above.

Comment: Next time post the config in your question rather than comments.  Can you confirm that all your nodes are talking?  What is the output of `nodetool -h 192.168.1.100 ring`.

Comment: My Nodetool is not working. Whn i open it after sometime it closedowwn. If possible tell me remedy to solve this nodetool issue.

Comment: When you say it's not working, are you getting an exception?  I see in your question that you are "clicking on it".  It's not designed to be run in a GUI, as it's a command-line tool.  So you'll need to open a terminal and run it that way.  I presume you are running on Windows, which is ok for development.  But just so you know, Cassandra is designed to run on Linux for production.

Comment: Thanks, the output of the nodetool is as below , 127.0.0.1       rack1       Up     Normal  3.03 MB         100.00%             2
345714693565637195

Comment: Did I answer your question?